# How to embed and run a jar file using python

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I have a python script that will run the jar file when script is executed:

```
import subprocess

jdk_path = "jdk\\bin\\java.exe"
jfx_path = "javafx\\lib"
modules = "javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing"
jar_file = "setup.jar"
command = jdk_path + " --module-path " + jfx_path + " --add-modules " + modules + " -jar " + jar_file

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

[image]

I want to create an **exe** of my script and include the setup.jar file in it using **auto-py-to-exe** or any other library. When the script file is clicked, the script calls the setup.jar file which is embedded inside my exe version of my script.

Answer (score 1):

I Wonder why you choosed this long way as you Can directly create and .exe file from your .jar file using launch4j.

Comment: Where to add the command value in launch4j section?

Comment: You can add the `--module-path javafx\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing` parameter in VM option of launch4j